# How to extract hostname within "ping -a" output?

Tags: regex, batch-file, extract, ping, hostname

I have to extract hostnames within "ping -a" outputs, but I can't figure it out, I was thinking about using regular expressions.
I would need to extract characters between `r`   and   `[` to get `computername.windowsdomain.` does it seem possible? 
I can't find good resources for batch regex online it's all about JS, PHP and .NET.

As I'm french the output of `ping -a` begins with:

```
Envoi d'une requête 'ping' sur XXXXXXXX.DOMAIN.NAME.com [127.0.0.1]
```

Comment: "r " (backspace after "r") <-- Say what? Do you mean `"r "` as in character r followed by space as your example or r\? Please provide a sample output line to make it possible to come up with a solution.

Comment: Can't you use the _hostname_ command instead ?

Comment: 'hostname' is executed locally in a batch script, i'd get my own hostname if I'd do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Batch files as such have no regex capabilities. There are options for filtering lines in text files or program outputs via `findstr` which uses its own interpretation of regular expressions which looks similar but is buggy and limited.

In any case, you can probably get away with something like the following:

```
set hostname=
for /f "skip=1 tokens=2" %%x in ('ping -n 1 -a so.me.i.p') do if not defined hostname set hostname=%x
echo %hostname%
```

Comment: A big thank you for your answer.

I found a solution only using tokens in a for /f loop:

`for /f "tokens=6 delims= " %%G in ('ping -a -n 1 -w 0 74.125.79.94 ^| find "["') do set hostname=%%G`
But i'm facing another problem here, I want to parse the output of `%%G` in a log but neither `echo %hostname%>>log.txt` or `echo %%G>>log.txt` will work. 
Any ideas about that ?

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('ping -n 1 -a 127.0.0.1^|find "["') DO CALL :sub %%i
ECHO hostname: %hostname%
ECHO domain: %domain%
ECHO whole chebang: %chebang%
GOTO :eof

:sub
SET hostname=%2
IF NOT %hostname:~0,1%==[ shift&GOTO sub
SET chebang=%1
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=." %%a IN ("%1") DO SET hostname=%%a&SET domain=%%b
GOTO :eof
```

Should work for you. Variable names are not my area of expertise...

Comment: A big thank you for your answer.

I found a solution only using tokens in a for /f loop:

`for /f "tokens=6 delims= " %%G in ('ping -a -n 1 -w 0 74.125.79.94 ^| find "["') do set hostname=%%G`
But i'm facing another problem here, I want to parse the output of `%%G` in a log but neither `echo %hostname%>>log.txt` or `echo %%G>>log.txt` will work. 
Any ideas about that ?

Comment: Depends on precisely where you put it - whether it's in the context of the FOR or outside. What actually happened when you tried your ECHO - did anything at all appear in the file? Try amending it to something like `echo FINDME %...` so that you can see whether the statement itself is being executed. Did you execute the code I've posted above - and did it produce the expected result?

Comment: If the output is `%G` then that means that the `ECHO` is not _within_ the `FOR` loop or that `G` is not a metavariable (loop-control variable) being set by the `FOR`. Possibly you're using `g` rather than `G` - metavariables are case-sensitive.